# .htaccess rule - identical first first parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^account /?i=a [L]
RewriteRule ^account/banners /?i=a&p=b [L]
```

Yet, when I go to `http://domain.com/account/banners`, it just shows the /account (?i=a) and not the /account/banners (?i=a&p=b)

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminate the `/account` expression with `$`. Otherwise, the pattern `^account` matches both `/account` and `/account/banners`.

```
RewriteRule ^account$ /?i=a [L]
RewriteRule ^account/banners /?i=a&p=b [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your first rule is catching things that *contain* account, rather than just equaling "account", try throwing a dollar sign in at the end